# Append to CSV file error

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I am trying to pipe a newly created user account info into a csv file, i want to store the random password, display name, and their email address as shown by the select statement, where did i go wrong?!

My Code:

```
$newUserData = New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName xxxx@xx.com -DisplayName xxxxx xxx -FirstName xxx -LastName xxxx

$newUserData | select password, displayname, userprincipalname | Export-Csv -Append -Force -Path "PATH TO FILE"
```

My Error:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run
the operation again.
At line:1 char:66
+ ... cipalname | Export-Csv -Append -Force -Path "PATH TO FILE" ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

the $newUserData output

```
> $newUserData
Password UserPrincipalName                      DisplayName isLicensed
-------- -----------------                      ----------- ----------
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx False
```

Comment: Are you quoting your arguments to those options?  I see `-DisplayName xxxxx xxx`.  What output do you get from entering `$newUserData` on its own line?

Comment: What is the actual value you're using in place of "PATH TO FILE"?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 if i type say $newUserData.Displayname, it will output the display name. mat- its simply a string to my file, i assure you it is correct i jusst dont want to display it.

Comment: Could you give an example path? e.g. C:\Temp\csvexample.csv and see if that works?  Also try `Test-Path 'path'` to ensure it works

Comment: Can the file not exist? When i did the path to a file that did not exist, it created the file and ran correctly, and then i ran the command again and it appended as expected, hmmm.

Comment: You have to specify the filename in the path argument.  e.g. `C:\Temp\Filename.csv`.  I haven't tested whether this will create intermediate folders that don't exist, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's an issue with the object getting sent to export-csv or the arguments themselves.  Try this:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Temp
$newUserData = New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName User@example.com -DisplayName User -FirstName User -LastName Test
$newUserData | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty 'isLicensed' | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\UserDat.csv -Append -Force
```